# Daily Limit Bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I've noticed this morning that once I hit 190, I stopped receiving rep.

I was on 9 votes (+9/-0) in this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40315/whats-the-name-for-a-bug-that-suddenly-breaks-things-but-has-always-been-present/40323#40323

Since then the answer has went to (+12/-1) yet my rep has not changed.

I don't care about the rep, just wanted to report the bug and see if it is already known.

[image: Screen shot]

Today's section of the rep log:

```
 2     40103 (10)
 2     40103 (10)
 2     40109 (10)
 2     40103 (10)
 2     40103 (10)
 2     40109 (10)
 2     40109 (10)
 2     40103 (10)
 2     40103 (10)
 2     40103 (10)
 2     40323 (10)
 2     40323 (10)
 2     40323 (10)
 2     40323 (10)
 2     40323 (10)
 2     40103 (10)
 2     40323 (10)
 2     40323 (10)
 2     40323 (10)
 2     40323 (10)
 2     40323 [0]
 2     40323 [0]
 3     40323 [-2]
 2     40323 [2]
 2     40323 [0]
 2     40323 [0]
-- 2011-01-26 rep +200  = 3597
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you checked your reputation report https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/reputation? That will give you an output which will show you exactly how much reputation you've received for the day.

Checking the rep graph on your profile page (which is all I can see) doesn't really help. It looks like you've actually earned 220 points - which can't be right. Post today's section of the report.

And don't forget the Stack Exchange day is UTC.

**UPDATE**

The reputation report - which is "the truth" - shows 200 points for the day, so you're not missing out on any rep. I'm asking around to see if anyone else has seen this.

**Here's what's going on**

The discrepancy is due to a deleted answer [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40290/what-is-the-best-way-to-count-time-spans/40293#40293) - (you should be able to see it, but if not it gained you an upvote).

The deletion causes a loss of the original 10 rep from the upvote because the upvote ceases, but the "real-time" counter thinks you've hit the rep cap and so doesn't add any more points.

If you hit the "recalc now" button at the bottom of the report you'll "get back" the missing 10 points because your history will be re-run and the deleted post won't count at all - it's as though it never happened. You will probably find that your rep goes down due to other deleted posts though.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had forgotten about that. It indicates it should be 13/92 not 13/82. I wonder why there is a discrepancy?

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Would a fix to update the "real-time" counters of all people (questioner and answerers) be on the cards? This would remove the confusion of the incorrect stats being displayed to users.

Comment: I also note that this missing 10 doesn't get added to my SO account ("real-time" counter OR /reputation listing)

Comment: @Dan - I wouldn't have thought so (I'm not a dev only a mod). I can't see it would be a common enough experience. You could post a bug question on Meta Stack Overflow. Reference this question and answer. The worst that will happen is that it will be marked `[status-declined]`.

Comment: @Dan unlikely; heavy caching is `[status-bydesign]`. Most of the time, 10 point reputation discrepancies are not a big deal.

Comment: @Dan - no rep earned from before a question is migrated isn't added to the target account. It is effectively lost. This has been asked on MSO before and marked as `[status-by-design]`. The vote does count to badge totals though.

Comment: Thanks for the responses @Mark and @Chris.

Answer (score 7):

ChrisF's answer is correct, but if you're interested in a blow-by-blow:

You wrote an answer to the question [What is the best way to count time spans?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40290/what-is-the-best-way-to-count-time-spans). That answer got 1 upvote, which gave you **10** reputation.

You also got **80** rep from [How many lines of code can a C# developer produce per month?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40100/how-many-lines-of-code-can-a-c-developer-produce-per-month/40103#40103), **30** rep from [vim tutorial for beginners](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40099/vim-tutorial-for-beginners/40109#40109), and **80** rep from [What's the name for a bug that suddenly breaks things but has always been present?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40315/whats-the-name-for-a-bug-that-suddenly-breaks-things-but-has-always-been-present/40323#40323).

At this point, you hit 200 reputation and the daily cap.

Then, [What is the best way to count time spans?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40290/what-is-the-best-way-to-count-time-spans) was migrated to Stack Overflow, so your answer was deleted. The reputation report immediately recalculated your score, removing the **10** rep you got from the now migrated answer and giving you **90** rep for [What's the name for a bug that suddenly breaks things but has always been present?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40315/whats-the-name-for-a-bug-that-suddenly-breaks-things-but-has-always-been-present/40323#40323), bringing you back to the daily cap again.

The front end immediately gets rid of the deleted answer, but doesn't immediately show your recalculated reputation, making it seem like you only got 190 rep before hitting the cap, even though you didn't.